# How do I use credentials from a JDNI Data Source in Non-Container Managed JPA (Spring Boot and Websphere)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, websphere

So I've trying to get Spring Boot with JPA 2.2 to work on a Websphere 8.5.5 Application Server. Since 8.5.5 only supports JPA 2.0, I believe that my only choice is to bypass Websphere and use non-container-managed persistence if I want to use JPA 2.2 features (please correct me if I'm wrong or if there's a better approach).

The problem is that existing applications currently use a JDNI data source and persistence managed by Websphere. I don't want to increase the workload of the DBAs by requiring them to do additional configuration, so I would like to pull the database credentials from the JDNI data source to setup my own connection with Spring Boot. Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instaed of using a JDBC datasource you can use the JNDI datasource:

```
spring.datasource.jndi-name=java:jboss/datasources/customers
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-connecting-to-a-jndi-datasource

Comment: At first, I was confused because I thought that transaction management was tied to the data source, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: That depends how the JNDI datasource (XA or not) is defined. But Spring Transaction uses JTA in that case. So you don't have to bother